# Column's MainAxisAlignment has no effect when nested in Column->Row

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get working the MainAxisAlignment property on the Column, but it's not working quite expected. Here is my code.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Account'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0, top: 0.0, bottom: 20.0),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.network(
                    'https://cdn.mydomain.com/Color/PNG/512/profile-512.png',
                    height: 72.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, // <<<=== this line
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('User\'s display name'),
                      Text('user@company.com'),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

My hierarchy is Container->Column->Card->InkWell->Row->Column. The innermost Column widget has a problem. I figured out that If I remove the first Column widget then the MainAxisAlignment just works fine.

But I can't do that as I want to build a Column layout with various **Card**s inside it, as you can see in the code.

Could somebody please let me know what is this weird behaviour and a solution around this?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap this column in a Container or SizedBox and set a double.infinity height for it.

The problem that's happening it's because a Column or any component which you don't set a height or width, will automatically adjust to the widgets inside of it.

```
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, //Add here
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('User\'s display name'),
                  Text('user@company.com'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

OBS: I personally like to use `MediaQuery` for this. eg: `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` to get the full height of the device, then, you can manipulate it, dividing by 2, 3, subtracting...

Comment: But I think the Container only wraps around its children, not the Column. Please correct me If I'm wrong. Because if I just use a Container->Text then the remaining space of the screen will be empty, by this property. But on the other hand, if I use a Column->Text (in children property) then the Column will expand to full height by default.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I've told the width, but the correct would be the height since you want to space around the elements. I'll update it.